# How to download a HTTPS website using username and password (For offline access)

Tags: download, wget, https, offline-files

I'm trying to download a complete video courses using my credentials from 
https://mitprofessionalx.mit.edu

I have tried https://github.com/coursera-dl/edx-dl but it doesn't work for this site.

I have also tried WinHTTrack but it fails (I think it supports only HTTP sites but this one is https):
[image]

Feel free if you have any other suggestions.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you just want the video then you might want to try a browser plugin that downloads videos. If you want to keep all the functionalities then I'm afraid that there isn't an easy way since you don't know what is the structure on their server side.

Comment: @MariusTancredi Yes I actually want all the content to be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

If you only need the videos, the best video downloader I've used is the Video DownloadHelper extension for Firefox. If there are a lot of videos it may take a while, but I don't know how you would automate the process...
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/

There is also wget which may do what you need but I have never used it.  https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/

Comment: videodownloadhelper is perfect, thank you